# Jest test case is failing in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have below method in nestjs in service class.

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<Certificate> {
    const result = await this.certificateRepository.findOne({ id });
    if (!result) {
        throw new NotFoundException(`Certificate with ID does not exist`);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have writtern below test case for the same.

```
it('should find one certificate', async () => {
        const id = '1';
        const certificate = await service.findOne(id);
        expect(repository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(repository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id);
        expect(certificate).toBeInstanceOf(Certificate);
    });
```

I am getting below error on the same.

I am not sure why it is returning `object` instead of `value`. if I cant modify the method can I modify this test case to retunr `object`?

WHat changes I should do in my testcase?

Comment: What is the error telling you? Of you look at `const result = await this.certificateRepository.findOne({ id });`, is `id` being passed directly to that method or as property `id` in an object? If you change it to ` expect(repository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ id, "1" });`

Comment: I am passing as property. method I dont have right to modify. can I do something in test case so that it can become successful?

Comment: What are you not allowed to change? The test assertions? The assertion is wrong when looking at the code. It will never pass in it's current state.

Comment: wow..it succeeded..thank you so much Alexander. I did not read entire comment earlier. you saved me. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the assertion to be the following:

```
expect(repository.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ id: "1" });
```

This will match what how the code uses `id` to call `certificateRepository.findOne`.